# What is add in for sharepoint designer workflow?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow

I am new to sharepoint. Can you please explain with example what is add in for sharepoint designer workflow and how to build it ? Can you please provide me any code or useful link? Can we be able to loop through a list using a SPD workflow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SPD custom Action is the term you're looking for - SP2007 code example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629922%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (you didn't say which version of SharePoint but the process is the same).

You can't loop through items with a normal workflow, its an event driven process. So you can start a workflow on creation or edit of an item in a list or library. When the event fires, you have the context of the item that caused the event.

In theory at least, you could write a custom action that did loop through all items in a list but that wouldn't be a very good idea IMHO. If you wanted to loop through a list of items, then perhaps a timer job might be the better approach?